# Parse multiple lines of text with powershell and export to csv

Tags: string, powershell, csv, parsing

I have multiple large log files that I'd like to export to CSV. To start with, I just want to split two parts, Date and Event. The problem I'm having is that not every line starts with a date.

Here is a sample chunk of log. Date/times are always 23 characters.  The rest varies with the log and event description.

[image]

I'd like the end result to look like this in excel.

[image]

Here's what I've tried so far but just returns the first 23 characters of each line.

```
$content = Get-Content myfile.log -TotalCount 50 
for($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Length; $i++) {
$a = $content[$i].ToCharArray()
$b = ([string]$a[0..23]).replace(" ","")
Write-Host $b }
```

Comment: could you post part of the log in text please so i can try something

Comment: 2017-09-04 12:31:11.343 General BOECD:: ProcessStartTime: 
Word: Length 3 [0917 1204 3029 ]
Hex: Length 6 [17 09 04 12 29 30]
. Display: False 
2017-09-04 12:31:11.479 General MelsecIoWrapper: Scan ended: device: 1, ScanStart: 9/4/2017 12:31:10 PM Display: False 
2017-09-04 12:31:11.705 General BOECD:: ProcessEndTime: 
Word: Length 3 [0917 1204 0931 ]
Hex: Length 6 [17 09 04 12 31 09]
. Display: False 
2017-09-04 12:31:13.082 General BOECD:: DV Data:

Comment: Note: In the actual log file, the Date always starts a line like the picture above. When I pasted the sample, it just wrapped everything together.

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46104169/edit) your question and put the sample text in there rather than responding to it. If for no other reason than the formatting issues you just encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the file in raw as a multi-line string, then use RegEx to split on the date pattern, and for each chunk make a custom object with the two properties that you want, where the first value is the first 23 characters, and the second value is the rest of the string trimmed.

```
(Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.csv -Raw) -split '(?m)(?=^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'|
    Where{$_}|
    ForEach-Object{
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Col1'=$_.Substring(0,23)
            'Col2'=$_.Substring(23).Trim()
        }
    }
```

Then you can pipe that to a CSV, or do whatever you want with the data. If the files are truly massive this may not be viable, but it should work ok on files up to a few hundred megs I would think. Using your sample text that output:

```
Col1                    Col2
----                    ----
2017-09-04 12:31:11.343 General BOECD:: ProcessStartTime: ...
2017-09-04 12:31:11.479 General MelsecIoWrapper: Scan ended: device: 1, ScanStart: 9/4/2017 12:31:10 PM Display: False
2017-09-04 12:31:11.705 General BOECD:: ProcessEndTime: ...
2017-09-04 12:31:13.082 General BOECD:: DV Data:
```

The `...` at the end of the two lines are where it truncated the multi-line value in order to display it on screen, but the value is there intact.

`(?=...)` is a so-called "positive lookahead assertion". Such assertions cause a regular expression to match the given pattern without actually including it in the returned match/string. In this case the match returns the empty string before a timestamp, so the string can be split there without removing the timestamp.

Comment: I would make the pattern `(?m)(?=^\d{4}-...)` to match timestamps at the beginning of a line specifically. The hyphens and colons don't need to be escaped, BTW.

Comment: Thanks, I have a hard time remembering what all counts as a reserved character in RegEx, so I tend to over-escape sometimes. I have also updated the answer to reflect your suggestion of only getting date/times at the beginning of a line, that is an excellent idea.